# can't use custom component in app.component.ts in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

1. I've created a **ionic 3** project with a sidebar.
2. I've defined couple of components in `components/component.module.ts` for lazy loading
3. I have a `profile-pic component` and I need to use it in **sidebar** which `app.component.html`
4. so to use this, I included `component.module.ts` in `app.component.ts` but got the error.

I've googled myself and found out that we can't include `component.module.ts` which is lazy loading in `app.component.ts`.

Not sure this is the correct answer but I need to use a component in `app.component.html`.

Any suggestions?

FYI, I wanna use custom components in Sidebar(which is `app.component.html`), not in Pages.

In pages, it works well if I import `component.module`.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can directly use your component as a `html tag` in your any files

Answer (score 0):

import component in app.modules.ts file

```
import { ComponentsModule } from '../../components/components.module'

imports: [
    ComponentsModule,

  ],
```

Comment: I've followed your steps exactly but it's not working.
`Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'user' since it isn't a known property of 'profile-pic'.`
Looks like we can't import lazy-loading components module in app.module.ts

Comment: the profile pic component cannot get access to the user variable. you will need to pass it as properties while calling the component in app.component

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me. Use the Component as a service. Declare it in the providers section of the main module, then import it in app.component.ts and inject it in the constructor of it.